# Is it possible to increase accuracy of floating point arithemtic with gcc?

Tags: c, floating-accuracy, spu

some program in C which does extensive floating point calculations get right results on a pc linux box, but wrong results on the SPE of the cell processor, but not on the PPU of the cell. I am using gcc compilers. I wonder if there is some gcc compilation option to increase rounding method or similar so I get single float precision calculations with more precision. I can not change to double, as on the SPE performance would drastic reduce

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the IBM [documentation for the differences from IEEE 754 on the SPU](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cellcomp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.cell.doc/proguide/spu_sp_diffs.html), it could be any number of things:

> - Zero results from arithmetic operations are always +0, never -0.
> - Denormal inputs from 2-149 to 2-126 to arithmetic operations are treated
>     as zero with the same sign. Arithmetic
>     operations never produce denormal
>     results, but produce +0 instead.
> - Arithmetic operations do not support IEEE Inf or NaN. These bit patterns
>     represent valid numbers. Overflow
>     results produce the maximum magnitude
>     value of appropriate sign.
> - Arithmetic operations use only the round-to-zero (chop, truncate)
>     rounding mode, regardless of the
>     setting of the rounding mode in the
>     Floating-Point Status and Control
>     Register (FPSCR), which affects only
>     double-precision arithmetic
>     operations.

Of course, on a related page, [you can also compile SPU code for strict IEEE conformance](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cellcomp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.cell.doc/proguide/fp_ieee.html):

> By default, XL C/C++ follows most, but
>   not all of the rules in the IEEE
>   standard. If you compile with the
>   -qnostrict option, which is enabled by default at optimization level -O3 or
>   higher, some IEEE floating-point rules
>   are violated in ways that can improve
>   performance but might affect program
>   correctness. To avoid this issue, and
>   to compile for strict compliance with
>   the IEEE standard, do the following:
>
> - Use the -qfloat=nomaf compiler option.
> - If the program changes the rounding mode at runtime, use the -qfloat=rrm
>     option.
> - If the data or program code contains signaling NaN values (NaNS), use the
>     -qfloat=nans option. (A signaling NaN is different from a quiet NaN; you
>     must explicitly code it into the
>     program or data or create it by using
>     the -qinitauto compiler option.)
> - If you compile with -O3, -O4, or -O5, include the option -qstrict after it.

Comment: thanks a lot, but unfortunately these options do not work on the gcc compiler